# Can't login any more after remapping alt-key (CtrlAltDel)

Tags: windows-7, remapping

I did a very stupid thing. I have disable the ALT-key in the registry, and now I can't enter any more the Ctrl-Alt-Del sequence to login.
What can I do?

Comment: Maybe boot in safe mode and edit the registry?

Comment: Have you tryed booting in Safe Mode? Edit: Meh, too late.

Comment: Did you try `ctrl`+`altgr`+`del`?

Comment: try to open the 'ease of access' tool in the bottom left corner. Check the 'type without the keyboard' option. Press the alt key with the mouse.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it is not working: In safe mode, the alt-key is not working neither. I disabled also the Atfgr key. On the On-Screen keyboard, I can press the alt-key, but it is not possible to do the ctrl-alt-del combination on this keyboard

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem, by using the startup option "Last known good configuration"